# How to know when an SKAction.repeat(action, count) is finished

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a video games with Swift & SpriteKit. I'm trying to make the level system of my game. Each levels has his own specifications (but it's not in the code right now).

However, I would like that when my SKaction.repeat is done, to move to an other scene (such as "Level completed" scene).

Do you know how can I do it ?

Here's my code :

```
func parametersLevel(){
    let spawn = SKAction.run(asteroids)
    let waitSpawn = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.8)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([waitSpawn,spawn])
    let spawnCount = SKAction.repeat(sequence, count: 750)
    self.run(spawnCount)
}
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: You do not want this, it will cause your game to end as soon as the last asteroid is created, not destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

From [run(_:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483103-run) instead of `self.run(spawnCount)` try with:

```
self.run(spawnCount, completion: {() -> Void in
   println("completed")
})
```

Comment: So if I want to go into an other scene i just put my transition instead of the  println right ?

Comment: Yes that should be it, try and see how it works for you :). Either your transition or a function call where the next transition code will be.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a key with your action, you can also do:

```
func parametersLevel(){
    let spawn = SKAction.run(asteroids)
    let waitSpawn = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.8)
    let sequence1 = SKAction.sequence([waitSpawn,spawn])
    let spawnCount = SKAction.repeat(sequence, count: 750)
    let endAction = SKAction.run{} //whatever you need your ending to be
    let sequence2 = SKAction.sequence([spawnCount ,endAction])
    self.run(sequence2,withKey:”spawn” )
}
```